# segmentation fault in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 14.04, ros indigo, verion 1.11.9.

I run this command:

`roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch`

Sometimes I have a segmentation fault (core dumped). Then I try to rerun the command. It can work as usual or fail again. Usually after three or four rerun it works correctly. You can see the error below (or on the picture [2.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14525311548846028.png)). I have no idea how to repeat this bug, but it appears quite often. Do you have any ideas how can I fix this problem?

I’ve seen some questions about segmentation fault but there was no answer which can help.

```
[ INFO] [1451979222.241382211, 0.190000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise Bumper[mobile_base/events/bumper]!
[ INFO] [1451979222.246247047, 0.190000000]: Kobuki(ns = //): Advertise IMU[mobile_base/sensors/imu_data]!
[ INFO] [1451979222.246448570, 0.190000000]: GazeboRosKobuki plugin ready to go! [mobile_base] [spawn_turtlebot_model-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/nadya/.ros/log/a2c15d8e-b37e-11e5-aa96-c485088c759e/spawn_turtlebot_model-4*.log
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 11524, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/nadya/.ros/log/a2c15d8e-b37e-11e5-aa96-c485088c759e/gazebo_gui-3.log]. log file: /home/nadya/.ros/log/a2c15d8e-b37e-11e5-aa96-c485088c759e/gazebo_gui-3*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223823/segmentation-fault-in-gazebo/) by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-01-11**:
Maybe try cross-posting on http://answers.gazebosim.org/.  Also cut and pasting text in here instead of screenshots will make it easier for others to search for the same problem.

**Comment by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) on 2016-01-11**:
@lucasw Thanks. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen this behavior on many machines that do not have nvidia cards (or proprietary nvidia drivers not installed/used). There doesn't seem to be much you can do about it apart from re-launching till it works AFAIK. See also related Gazebo tickets: [startup errors on some gpus](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/132/startup-error-on-some-gpus), [segfault of tests in intel video cards](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/832/segfault-of-tests-in-intel-video-cards).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KavitShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/60181/kavitshah/) on 2020-12-08**:
I am facing the same issue, I have NVIDIA graphics card with proprietary drivers. Still the issue persists.
Did anyone find a solution?

**Comment by [SC0d3r](https://answers.ros.org/users/78020/sc0d3r/) on 2021-07-23**:
I am facing the same issue here on ros noetic and gazebo 11.5 did anyone found any solution for this problem?